# kohlenstoff-basiert oder Kohlenstoff-basiert?

Tags: compound, capitalization, compound-adjective

Wenn ich in zusammengesetzten Adjektiven wie "kohlenstoffbasiert", die als ersten Bestandteil ein Substantiv enthalten, zur besseren Lesbarkeit einen Bindestrich einfügen möchte, muss ich dann den substantivischen Teil groß ("Kohenstoff-basiert") oder weiterhin klein ("kohlenstoff-basiert") schreiben?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120151/discussion-on-question-by-schtandard-kohlenstoff-basiert-oder-kohlenstoff-basier).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ja, das Substantiv muss in diesem Fall groß geschrieben werden:

> Bei einer Verbindung aus Substantiv und Adjektiv / Partizip behält das Substantiv seine Großschreibung (D 68). Die Zusammenschreibung ist hier vorzuziehen.
>
> eine Cloud-basierte Lösung (besser: eine cloudbasierte Lösung)
> eine Putin-kritische Gruppierung (besser: eine putinkritische Gruppierung)

[Duden, Bindestrich-Regeln](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich)
oder [Regelwerk entsprechend den Empfehlungen des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung 2016](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf), § 55 (2).

Wie aus dem Zitat oben sichtbar, sollte aber auf solche Bindestrichkonstruktionen eher verzichtet werden.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120149/discussion-on-answer-by-idmean-kohlenstoff-basiert-oder-kohlenstoff-basiert).