# Authoritative source for apostrophe rule in adjectives from names (Gauß’sche, gaußsche, but not Gaußsche)?

Tags: spelling, proper-noun, reformed-orthography, apostrophe

Most sources I can find state that under current spelling rules, adjectives formed from proper names should either keep the capital letter and use an apostrophe, or else have lowercase but no apostrophe.  So *Gauß’sche* and *gaußsche* are both correct, but not *Gaußsche*.  For instance, [this stackexchange answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5316/why-does-fresnelsche-have-an-apostrophe-and-gau%C3%9Fsche-doesnt) describes and illustrates the rule carefully.

However, some other sources disagree with this rule, recommending the *Gaußsche* form as correct and/or saying that *Gauß’sche* is incorrect.  It seems at least that many native speakers hold this belief.  Some people suggest that this may be because at some period, *Gaußsche* was indeed the accepted form, but that it changed to *Gauß’sche* in the 1996 or 2006 orthographic reforms.  But having skimmed/searched those reforms and several summaries of them, I’ve not found where this rule is discussed.  More generally, none of the online sources I found gave authoritative sources for their claims.

Overall, there is clearly some confusion and disagreement about this rule, even among well-educated native speakers, so **I would like to find an authoritative source presenting this rule, and ideally also noting if it has been different in the past**, and I have so far been unable to find such a source.  An ideal source would be a reference within the spelling reforms themselves, or another up-to-date document from the [*Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung*](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com) itself.  If that can’t be found, then e.g. something from a well-established dictionary or similar publication would be good; or, generally, whatever best source can be found.

Comment: There is no authoritative source.

Comment: Related question on Academia.SE [Beweis einer Baudet'schen Vermutung](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/162979/when-the-title-of-an-article-is-printed-differently-in-the-front-back-matter-ver)

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31430/34192. Note that "gaußsche" belongs to mathematical terminology - see my answer to the above question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[§ 62](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6195) of the official orthograpic rules states that adjectives derived from personal names using the ending *-(i)sch* are written with a lower case first letter, unless the personal name is clarified using an apostrophe:

> Kleingeschrieben werden adjektivische Ableitungen von Eigennamen auf *-(i)sch*, außer wenn die Grundform eines Personennamens durch einen Apostroph verdeutlicht wird, ferner alle adjektivischen Ableitungen mit anderen Suffixen.

This implies that the correct forms are *Einstein'sche* and *einsteinsche*.

Comment: Aber nach Paragraph 63 ist Großschreibung ohne Apostroph unter bestimmten Bedingungen möglich. Also wieder drei Möglichkeiten, wie Hubert in seiner Antwort auf die verlinkte Frage schon vor acht Jahren geschrieben hat.

Comment: @DavidVogt In Paragraph 63 gibt es keinen Hinweis auf die Korrektheit einer Großschreibung ohne Apostroph. Bitte zitiere, wo du das liest. In der Antwort von Hubert Schölnast wird das kleingeschriebene Adjektiv als Teil eines Namens großgeschrieben. Das hat aber nun mit der Ableitung von Adjektiven aus Personennamen nichts zu tun. Diese Regel gilt für alle Adjektive ohne Ausnahme. Du würdest daraus, dass Wörter am Satzanfang groß geschrieben werden, doch hoffentlich auch nicht folgern, dass man Adjektive, Verben, Pronomen usw. auch groß schreiben darf.

Comment: Alles unter (2).

Comment: @DavidVogt Unter dem § 62 gibt es kein (2). Du meinst vermutlich den § 60 (Schreibung von geografischen Namen). Für den gilt aber, was ich bereits gesagt habe: Du kannst aus einer Regel, dass in bestimmten Fällen eine besondere Schreibung für eine Vielzahl von Wortarten gilt, keine allgemeine Regel für eine bestimmte Wortart ableiten. Dass ich am Anfang dieses Satzes das *dass* groß schreibe, bedeutet nicht, dass man *dass* groß schreiben kann.

Comment: @user47844 - §63 (2) allows e.g. Gaußsche Normalverteilung as over time it has become an expression, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be the same mechanism as in [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/63117/1696) for adjectives with a substantive component:

If the substantive is separated - by hyphen or apostrophe, latter permitted for **proper nouns** in § 97 of [Rechtschreibregeln](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) - it retains its substantive property of starting with an uppercase letter. While in unseparated form there is no reason for uppercase,  *Einsteinsche Relativitätstheorie*, *Ohmsches Gesetz*, *Wheatstonesche Brückenschaltung*, *Gaußsche Summenformel* may be considered as fixed phrases with special meaning and due that reason qualify for uppercase. (§ 63, 2.2). *Gaußsche Schnürsenkel* would not qualify, so there is a context-dependency with the context being omitted in the question.